# Error in C program smaller than expected

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I have done a C program to compute a solution of a differential equation along  path. The code has been done using double precision.

I do not understand why I do get an error of 10^-21 (absolute error) only. It is supposed double precision gives only about 16 digits of precision.

The error is computed but doing the difference of a constant that it is known to be invariant during the mathematical process to find the solution. The details of this are not relevant. My question is only how is possible to get less error that the supposed limit of precision used.

Using gcc I have the following precision parameters:

```
Min Epsilon Double: 0.000000000000000222044604925031
Digits mantissa (bit precission) double: 53
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the relative error is on the order of 10^-21 then I would attribute that to chance.

Comment: Is 10^-21 the absolute or the relative error?

Comment: You are aware that 16 digits of precision is sufficient to measure the distance from here to Pluto to the nearest millimetre?

Comment: How do you calculate your error.  Are you comparing the to some anlytically known result, or is it something your algorithm spits out.

Comment: @Bathsheba checking the order of magnitude of your errors is a legitimate smell-test.  If the results don't make sense, his real "error" might be an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer may be that you use GCC on x86/x86_64, the calculations are not too complex, so the compiler optimizes them to be processed internally in 80-bit floating point registers which have `long double` precision, thus giving you better results.

Or it may be that you use the word *precision* to describe *absolute error*, and when the actual values are on the order of 10<sup>-5</sup> and the *relative error* is on the order of 10<sup>-16</sup>, the *absolute error* is on the order of 10<sup>-21</sup>.

Or something else, depending on the context.
You see, the details are actually relevant.

Comment: @JanusGowda: Try compiling with no optimizations ("`-O0`"), and see if the results differ. If they start to make more sense, perhaps the first point of my answer is the case. See also here for more compiler options: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-ffloat-store-945

Comment: The second point (relative error) can't be the explanation because the value is of about 3.

The program has been compiled with optimization -03. But also it has been compiled with this flag the small code that gives min_epsilon to be of about 10^-16.

Comment: @JanusGowda: The minimum value of double won't change because of compiler options. Also, make sure you check with both "`-O0`" and "`-O3`". Note that the big O is not a zero (**not** "`-03`" as you write).

Comment: Yes, the optimization level was the issue. It was jumpint to long doubles instead of doubles automatically.
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values (`float` and `double`) use scientific notation in binary.

So, part of the bits used by a `double` are the significative (binary digits) while others are the exponents.

Check the documentation for maximum and minimum values for such types, it also specifies how close to 0 an -0 they can get.

Comment: I have checked that.

Min Epsilon Double: 0.000000000000000222044604925031
Digits mantissa (bit precission) double: 53